# Selenium exception when using chrome driver

Tags: grails, selenium, geb, selenium-chromedriver

While doing same testing with Geb in a Grails application, the tests passed when runned with default's HtmlUnitDriver.

But, when I changed to ChromeDriver, I was receiving

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is not
>   currently interactable and may not be manipulated

when testing the login page.

The exception was thrown immediately after setting the emailField (selected through its id '#username'). The strange thing was that I was seeing the browser setting the value on the field, but after that (and before executing the following line of the code) it throwed the Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that the login page had 2 elements with id="username" (one of which was a hidden field), and that was the reason of the exception. When I changed the id of the login page to another value (and updated the selector), the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same exception when I was trying to access a text field on popup window.

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

I realized that the window is shown in two places and verified that indeed the Xpath being used to identify the text field on popup window was showing me two results in the FireBug+FirePath Plugin.

I updated the Xpath such that it would uniquely identify text field on the second popup window and the issue was resolved.